# Style buttons and tabs in header

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I don't have too much experience with front end so I'm trying to learn and I'm running into an issue that probably has a simple solution. I have 4 components, 2 buttons and 2 tabs. I want them styled in a header at the top of the page such that one button is at the top left with some padding, the other button is at the top right with some padding, and the tabs are centered in the middle. I'm using `jquery` `jquery mobile` and `angularjs`. I did some research on them and didn't see anything in the api that would easily accomplish this so I figured I would need custom css. Right now my components are:

```
<button>Button 1</button>
<div data-role="tabs" id="tabs"> 
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li ng-class="{active: navigation.isSelected(1)}" > 
                <button ng-click="navigation.selectTab(1)">Tab 1</button> 
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active: navigation.isSelected(2)}"> 
                <button class="ui-btn-active" ng-click="navigation.selectTab(2)">Tab 2</button> 
            </li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<button>Button 2</button>
```

I tried wrapping the whole thing in another div and set the floats but when I tried setting the float on the second button to right it put it on a new line, and I do not believe there is a float for center. Once again I'm pretty new to this so any guide in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Put a div around the elements, set it's `position` to `relative`
- Give the tab div and the two buttons `classes` or `ids` and use those to set  the tab div and the two buttons `position` to `absolute`
- Set the elements' `top`, `left`, and `right` properties as needed
- You'll need to set the width of each element with percentages so that they wont try to overlap each other

You will likely need to adjust the values to suit your needs but the below should work for you:

Here is a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2m9dLqot/1/)

**CSS**

```
.myHeader{
    position: relative;
    height:62px;
}
.left-btn{
    width:10% !important; 
    position: absolute;
    left: 1%;
}
.right-btn{
    width:10% !important;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1%;
}
#tabs{
    width:75%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 12%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="myHeader">
<button class="left-btn">Button 1</button>
<div data-role="tabs" id="tabs"> 
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li ng-class="{active: navigation.isSelected(1)}" > 
                <button ng-click="navigation.selectTab(1)">Tab 1</button> 
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active: navigation.isSelected(2)}"> 
                <button class="ui-btn-active" ng-click="navigation.selectTab(2)">Tab 2</button> 
            </li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="right-btn">Button 2</button>
</div>
```